# Input Variables not getting converted using loop function

Tags: python, loops

I have this data set, I need to change the values of "Day" column into "weekday" and "weekend"

```
    Date    Country Confirmed   Recovered   Deaths  Active  Day
0   2020-01-22  Afghanistan 0   0   0   0   Wednesday
1   2020-01-22  Albania 0   0   0   0   Wednesday
2   2020-01-22  Algeria 0   0   0   0   Wednesday
3   2020-01-22  Andorra 0   0   0   0   Wednesday
4   2020-01-22  Angola  0   0   0   0   Wednesday
```

I am trying this loop in python (Jupyter) notebook

```
for i in data['Day'].unique():

    if i == ['Sunday','Saturday']:
        i = 'weekend'
    else:
        i = 'weekday'
```

It is working but the values remains the same.

please help

Answer (score 0):

You are changing only the loop variable **i**, not the data itself. This is not what you want. The datastructure where the value comes from will not be changed.

The complete solution is unknown for me, because you did not define what **data** is exactly.
I think **day** is e.g. 'Sunday' and you want to overwite it with 'weekend'. The **index** is probably required for setting the weekday

```
for index, day in enumerate(data['Day'].unique()):
    if day in ['Sunday','Saturday']:
        weekday = 'weekend'
    else:
        weekday = 'weekday'
    # Now you have to overwrite e.g. 'Saturday' by 'weekend'
    # TODO: Check how to set the weekday in data
    data['Day'][index] = weekday
```